# Why "would be" put in ”quell the rage of would be wordsmiths“

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> In general understanding the proper usage can help dispel confusion or quell the rage of **would be** wordsmiths.

I can understand if the sentence has been written as:

> In general understanding the proper usage can help dispel confusion or quell the rage of wordsmiths.

I am not sure what "**would be**" is doing here?

The [full source](https://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-difference-between-an-immigrant-and-an-emigrant.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes a lot more sense with additional context:

> The terms emigrant and immigrant are often incorrectly used, creating confusion at best, and annoyance of English teachers at worst. In general understanding the proper usage can help dispel confusion or quell the rage of would be wordsmiths.

Ironically (for being an article on those particular about English), the passage suffers from some stylistic issues.

For instance, the term you question should actually be written as **would-be wordsmiths**, with a hyphen for the compound adjective.

In this case, *would-be wordsmiths* refers to people who aspire to use English correctly (like English teachers) and who understand the difference between the words *emigrant* and *immigrant*—but who aren't actually employed in that profession.

It's effectively saying that if everybody used those two words correctly, it would not only prevent confusion in general but also the annoyance of those who feel the need to keep offering correction.

---

*Would-be* as an adjective comes from something like:

> "I would be a doctor if I could. Instead, I've had to satisfy myself with some first-aid courses and general knowledge. I'm afraid that all I'll ever be is a *would-be* doctor."

In slang (or informal use, as it actually has a dictionary definition), this is also known as a [*wannabe*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wannabe).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : a person who wants or aspires to be someone or something else or who tries to look or act like someone else

Comment: I think there's an accidental repeat of "be a" in your first quote. "I would be a be a".